# Spring-xd tap with filter?

Tags: spring-xd

I have a stream "myStream" of text records of different types, say "A", "B", "C", and so on...Each type of records needs to be processed differently. I want to create multiple taps on "myStream" for each type: tapA, tapB, tapC, etc. But it seems tap doesn't have any filtering capability. Is that true or am I missing something? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have filter on a tap stream. You can see tap as a regular stream that has *source channel* (tap channel) set and this source channel can be combined with *multiple* processors and a *single* sink.

See this example:

```
xd:>stream create test --definition "http | log" --deploy

xd:>http post --data test

xd:>stream create tap-test --definition "tap:stream:test.http > filter --expression=payload.contains('a') | log" --deploy

xd:>http post --data test
xd:>http post --data apple
```

and in the container log you would see something like this:

```
2015-05-19 11:48:36,276 1.2.0.SNAP  INFO pool-16-thread-11 sink.test - test
2015-05-19 11:48:41,445 1.2.0.SNAP  INFO pool-16-thread-17 sink.test - apple
2015-05-19 11:48:41,445 1.2.0.SNAP  INFO xd.localbus-2 sink.tap-test - apple
```

Note the payload 'apple' comes out of regular and tap stream.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me now. My confusion was that I used "tap:stream:test | filter ..." instead of "tap:stream:test > filter ..."

Comment: oh ok. Anytime you use named channel (tap:, queue: etc.,) then, you would use this angle bracket `>` symbol.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get the same results

    2016-05-02T14:46:55+0300 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO pool-81-thread-12 sink.test - test

    2016-05-02T14:47:02+0300 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO pool-81-thread-4 sink.test - apple
`